# Check Mandatory fields in loop

Tags: jquery

I have to check if all mandatory fields are filled in before I send them to database. This is done trough column IDKarakteristike. If the field is mandatory then value of this column is True if not it is False.
Here's a code snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/nzx3tdgp/

There's a problem with the jQuery: first it checks on button click if all mandatory fields are validated and sends warning, that's works ok. But when I then fill in the filed's that where not filled in first time and click the botton the warning still remains. I need the jquery to loop somehow and check for mandatory fields again. Can someone help me with this code? Thanks in advance !

```
$(function () {
    $("#myButton").on("click", function () {
        // Loop all span elements with target class
        $(".IDKarakteristike").each(function (i, el) {
            // Skip spans which text is actually a number
            if (!isNaN($(el).text())) {
                return;
            }

            // Get the value
            var val = $(el).text().toUpperCase();
            var isRequired = (val === "TRUE") ? true :
                             (val === "FALSE") ? false : undefined;

            // Mark the textbox with required attribute
            if (isRequired) {
                // Find the form element
                var target = $(el).parents("tr").find("input,select");

                if(target.val()) {
            return;
        }

                // Mark it with required attribute
                target.prop("required", true);

                // Just some styling
                target.css("border", "1px solid red");
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: why not just pull the code to do  you mandatory checks into a function and call the function again when you need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add jquery validate plugin in your code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add this for validation:

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
        IDKarakteristike:{
            required: true
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the native `required` HTML attribute?

```
<input type="text" required>
```

Comment: Because every element is dynamicaly generated from database, and the number will grow over time.